# Regardless of battery charge, when unplugged Ubuntu displays critical battery message and hibernates

Tags: 11.10, battery

Regardless of battery charge, when unplugged Ubuntu displays critical battery message and hibernates. I can only seem to change it to either shutdown or hibernate.

This does not happen when using windows 7 on the same computer. Windows 7 gives a good few hours on a full charge indicating that it is not a battery problem.

Any help? I really don't want to have to use windows but its kinda pointless having a netbook that doesn't work when not plugged in!

I'm using a toshiba nb250 and the most up to date 11.10 ubuntu distro. I use to get the critical battery message before on the previous ubuntu but it never shut down or hibernated my computer.

Comment: @Salem Thankyou for your help :) I copied and pasted this into the terminal and it seemed to sort it out.. Im so happy that Im not forced to use windows on battery power anymore!

gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/general/use_time_for_policy false

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11378614&postcount=5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess your computer is configured to suspend/shutdown when he thinks the battery level is critical. To change that behaviour, you need to install `dconf-tools`. Then open it in dash (dconf Editor), and follow this path:

```
 org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > power
```

And change the value of `critical-battery-action` to *nothing*.
Also, if the battery is marked as broken, you can also uncheck the option `notify-perhaps-recall`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the action (IE: Hibernate) open dconf-editor: org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > power and just uncheck: use-time-for-policy, this will force the OS to use the percentage base instead of the ACPI Bios.