# Don't want to suspend when closing lid

Tags: laptop, 12.04, dell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

It's a Dell d630. Installed 12.04. I'm using an external monitor, so I'd like to close the lid and have it continue to work.

However, regardless of what I put in the Power Management option, it insists in suspending when I close the lid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Hello I just found this myself in Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

click on "unity dash" and type in the command line "power"
open power options by clicking on power icon in unity display screen

ensure that lid closed option is set to "nothing"  THEN click on brightness settings link under where it tells you how much your battery is charged.

in the new window called Brightness and LOCK - you can turn off the lock option (which I assume is the suspend since we already set close lid to do nothing in power options

My favorite option in this page though is the check box require password when waking from suspend.  Remove this, and you never get prompted for a silly password after closing the lid on your laptop

Hope this helps

Comment: And welcome to AskUbuntu. Hope you enjoy tweaking the system more.

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/83225/33871) but instead of changing `critical-battery-action`, change `lid-close-ac-action` and `lid-close-battery-action` to the value `nothing`.

Comment: This is interesting - I also have a D630, and lid-close-ac-action and lid-close-battery-action were already set to 'nothing'. However whenever I shut the clamshell, the external monitor used to go blank... until I unchecked the "require password" checkbox. Maybe it's some new 'negative improvement' that only affects d630s - until recently there was no issue.